# Использование package в Java

Tags: java, package

Не могу понять, что делаю не так.
Есть следующий код:

```
package Main;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("something");
    }
}
```

Java-файл находится в директории `C:\app\xyz\some\Main\`
При компиляции ошибок никаких не выдает, компилирую из той же директории командой `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\javac.exe" Main.java`, ошибок при этом не возникает (точнее, о них не сообщается).
На следующем же этапе при попытке запустить .class-файл командой java Main выдает что-то наподобие

> Could find or load class Main

При том, без package всё работает прекрасно.

P.s пробовал добавлять 'полный' путь до класс-файла при запуске, а-ля xyz.some.Main.Main, но выходит всё вышеописанное.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Положите Main.class в папку Main и вызывайте относительно **внешней** (не Main, а внешней) папки

```
java Main.Main
```

Или уберите package

Answer (score -2):

Package нужно использовать, если вы компилируете файл "*.jar", а у вас файл "*.class". Package здесь вроде не нужен.
Кстати, как я знаю, в package не нужно указывать имя класса. Т. е. "xyz.some.Main", а не "xyz.some.Main.Main".